# Array of Objects ordered by similarity to neighbour

Tags: javascript, node.js, algorithm, computer-science

I really hope you can help me I have an array of objects and I need an algorithm or a pointer to something to read up on that will sort them by similarity to their neighbours.

For Example

```
[ 
  {a:12,b: 7,c: 5}, 
  {a: 5,b: 5,c: 5}, 
  {a: 3,b: 3,c: 3}, 
  {a: 5,b: 7,c: 5},
  {a:12,b: 7,c: 5}
]
```

becomes

```
[
  {a: 5,b: 5,c: 5},
  {a: 5,b: 7,c: 5},
  {a:12,b: 7,c: 5}, 
  {a:12,b: 7,c: 5}, 
  {a: 3,b: 3,c: 3},
]
```

I have a REPL here...

https://repl.it/@idrise/ThoseWellmadeMonitors

I have brute forced it but it doesn't get the best score and it takes eons on big arrays.

This is how the score is calculated, the higher the score the better !

```
function scoreArray(array) {
  let score = 0;
  for (let f = 1; f < array.length; f++) {
    score += howSimilarAreObjects(array[f - 1], array[f]);
  }
  return score;
}

function howSimilarAreObjects(object1, object2) {
  let score = 0;
  Object.keys(object1).forEach(curValue => {
    if (object1[curValue] === object2[curValue]) {
      score++;
    }
  });
  return score;
}
```

Any help greatly appreciated,

Idris

Comment: Why does `c` property sorts descending while the others do ascending..?

Comment: What does "similarity" mean? How is `{3, 3, 3}` not more similar to `{5, 5, 5}` than to `{12, 7, 5}`?

Comment: You might want to lookup JavaScript implementations of ‘cosine similarity’

Comment: A [similarity measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Similarity_function) does not provide an [ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order) that would be necessary for a sort. Or are you trying to sort them in descending order by their similarity to a *specific* other element?

Comment: In the repl is the score function which describes the output required. I manually sorted the result. The order is not important the proximity to objects with matching fields is important.

Comment: looking for cosine similarity

Comment: sadly it's not a match :(

Comment: OK, you're not looking for a comparison function to use with `sort`. This is "just" an optimisation problem on the permutations of the input.

Comment: I fear this is actually an NP-complete problem. You could model the array as the [path of a travelling salesperson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem), where each object forms a vertex of a fully connected graph, and the edge costs would be the dissimilarity between the pair of linked objects (meaning that edges between similar objects will be preferred, and their sum maximised). Maybe you could find a good metric in the multidimensional space (one dimension per object property) though that helps with an approximation

Comment: does the objects have the same common keys?

Answer (score 0):

You could run every element against each other and get the similarity between the both objects. Then take the groups and get the objects with the highest similarity first and then with the lower ones. By pushing them to the result set, filter the array by already seen objects.

```js
const similar = (a, b) => Object.keys(a).filter(k => a[k] === b[k]).length;

var array = [{ a: 12, b: 7, c: 5}, { a: 5, b: 5, c: 5}, { a: 3, b: 3, c: 3}, { a: 5, b: 7, c: 5}, { a: 12, b: 7, c: 5}],
    groups = {},
    used = new Set,
    result = [];

array.forEach((a, i) => 
    array
        .slice(i + 1)
        .forEach(b => (s => (groups[s] = groups[s] || []).push(a, b))(similar(a, b))));

Object
    .keys(groups)
    .reverse()
    .forEach(k => result.push(...groups[k].filter(o => !used.has(o) && used.add(o))));

console.log(result);
console.log(groups);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I can't make sense of these `groups`. You seem to push arbitrary objects in there. If you would at least push *pairs* (where each pair has the same similarity) I'd understand, but what do the un-paired objects in a group have to do with each other?

Comment: I doubt that this always finds the optimal solution. A greedy "biggest first" algorithm usually doesn't fare well on combinatoric problems.

Comment: Really elegant piece of code, doesn't solve the problem as Bergi says, but gets pretty close. Sadly it's super memory hungry and crashes out node on just 1000 objects in an array :(

Answer (score 0):

Let us define a function that you wish to minimize:

> minimal sum of squared distance between every pair of neighbors

If you were to iterate over all `n!` permutations, and choose the lowest total, you would have achieved your goal. Of course, `n!` is way too expensive, so we have to use something simpler.

You can take a greedy approximation, which is simply:

1. start by any neighbor
2. continue with the nearest neighbor to the last-added one
3. repeat 2 until you finish

This will not be optimal, but will not be too far off either. And it is quite cheap to calculate (O(n^2), intead of O(n!)).

Using this function, you are essentially trying to solve the [traveling salesman problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem) (TSP), on which a lot has been written, and for which a lot of approximations exist. The general problem is np-hard, so the normal approach is to choose a not-so-expensive approximation, of which the simplest may be the greedy approach outlined above.